# Prove the double angle formula

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, where $X\in U(-1,1)$ and $Y$ assumes the values of $+1$ and $-1$ with probabilities $1/2$.

Show first that $Z=X+Y = U(-2,2)$ by finding the distribution function of Z.

Then translate that fact into a statement about the corresponding characteristic functions.

Finally show that $\sin(2t) = 2 \sin(t) \cos(t)$

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: If I could find the dist. of Z I believe I could get this. However I am confused with the statement "$Y$ assumes the values of $+1$ and $-1$ with probabilities $1/2$

Answer (score 1):

PDF of $U(-1,1)$ is 
$$
f_X(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{cl}
\frac 12 & -1 \le x \le 1 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array}\right .
$$
PMF ([Probability mass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function)) of second RV
$$
f_Y'(y) = \left \{ \begin{array}{cl}
\frac 12 & y \in \{-1,1\} \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array}\right .
$$
I put $'$ to the $f_Y$ to distinguish it from actual PDF of $Y$ which is given below.

Using generalized functions concept ([Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29)) you can rewrite them as
$$
f_X(x) = \frac 12\left [\theta(x+1)-\theta(x-1)\right] \\
f_Y(y) = \frac 12 \left [ \delta(y+1) + \delta(y-1)\right]
$$
where $\theta(x)$ is [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and $\delta(x)$ [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

If you have $Z = X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then
$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy
$$
which is a convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$ w.r.t variable $y$.
$$
f_Z(z) = \frac 14 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left [ \theta(z-y+1)-\theta(z-y-1)\right ] \cdot \left [\delta(y+1) + \delta(y-1 \right ]dy = \\
= \frac 14 \left \{ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left [\theta (z-y+1) - \theta(z-y-1)\right ] \delta(y+1)dy \right \} + \\
\frac 14 \left \{ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left [\theta(z-y+1)- \theta(z-y-1)\right ]\delta(y-1)dy \right \} = 
$$
If you use property of the Dirac delta function 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-\tau) \delta(\tau)d\tau = f(t)
$$
you can state integral as
$$
\frac 14 \left [ \theta(z+2) - \theta(z)\right ] + \frac 14 \left [ \theta(z)-\theta(z-2) \right ] = \frac 14 \left[ \theta(z+2)-\theta(z-2)\right ]
$$
which is PDF of the $U(-2,2)$.

So 
$$
f_Z(z) = \left \{\begin{array}{cl}
\frac 14 & -2 \le z \le 2 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array}\right .
$$

### PS

I'm not sure I understood second part about double angle, since that identity is always true, regardless whether argument is some number or RV.

Answer (score 1):

There is a $\frac12$ chance that $Y=1$ in which case the distribution of $X+Y$ is
$$
f_1(x)=\left\{\begin{align}
\tfrac12\qquad&\text{if }x\in[0,2]\\
0\qquad&\text{otherwise}
\end{align}\right.
$$
There is a $\frac12$ chance that $Y=-1$ in which case the distribution of $X+Y$ is
$$
f_{-1}(x)=\left\{\begin{align}
\tfrac12\qquad&\text{if }x\in[-2,0]\\
0\qquad&\text{otherwise}
\end{align}\right.
$$
Thus, the distribution of $X+Y$ is
$$
\frac12f_{-1}(x)+\frac12f_1(x)=\left\{\begin{align}
\tfrac14\qquad&\text{if }x\in[-2,0]\\
\tfrac14\qquad&\text{if }x\in[0,2]\\
0\qquad&\text{otherwise}
\end{align}\right.
$$
which is the [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of the distributions of $X$ and $Y$. That is, the distribution is $U(-2,2)$.

I don't see a relation between this and the double angle formula for $\sin$.

Answer (score 0):

For the double angle formula:

Using $sin(2t) = sin(t+t)$, apply the sum formula for sine: $sin(a+b) = sin(a)cos(b) + cos(a)sin(b)$